# Is it a good practice to put all form inputs inside divisions?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

Is there a downside to putting all your form `input` tags inside `div`? I find you have the most control and clean code by doing that:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                margin-top: 0.5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="myFormScript.php" method="post">
            <div>Name: <input type="text" size="50" name="user-name"></div>
            <div>Password: <input type="password" size="50" name="pwd"></div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Ford">I have a Ford</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Audi">I have an Audi</div>
            <div><textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10">You can type stuff here!</textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a particular downside in doing that

Comment: Why would you do that? What purpose does the `<div>` serve?

Answer (score 1):

There so no such downside of using `input` inside `div`.

But if you want to improve your `form` interactive you can use `label` instead of keep text directly inside `div`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            input {
                margin-top: 0.5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="myFormScript.php" method="post">
            <div>
              <label for="username">Name: </label>
              <input id="username" ype="text" size="50" name="user-name" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label for="password">Password: </label>
              <input id="password" type="password" size="50" name="pwd" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="ford" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Ford" />
              <label id="ford"> I have a Ford </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="audi" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Audi"/>
              <label for="audi"> I have an Audi </label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <textarea name="" id="" cols="50" rows="10">You can type stuff here!</textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you really want to use div or make a good interface then you should use bootstrap

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container w-75 mx-auto">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="password">
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                  I have a Ford
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                  I have an Audi
                </label>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Textarea</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
    </div>
   
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is neither necessary nor sufficient to "make a good interface".

Comment: how can you say that  Bootstrap is neither necessary nor sufficient to "make a good interface". if it not sufficient then why the most famous company are using bootstrap on their website